# QGIS download and install full package on redhat 5

Tags: download, installation, arcgis, qgis

I need a direct link to download QGIS and ArcGIS softwares those will be compatible with redhat 5 and can some one help me to install it on redhat 5 ??? i need a full package?
Also I would like to ask you is there any version of ARCGIS that compatible with redhat 5

Comment: I need your feed back as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various parts of the ArcGIS platform run on RHEL 5:

- ArcGIS Server [10.2.x](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/#/ArcGIS_for_Server/015100000072000000/), [10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/#/ArcGIS_10_1_for_Server/015100000072000000/), [10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/systemrequirements/index.html#/ArcGIS_Server_10_System_Requirements/015100000072000000/)
- Portal for ArcGIS [10.2.x](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/#/Portal_for_ArcGIS/01510000008p000000/)
- ArcGIS Engine [10.2.x](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/#/ArcGIS_Engine/015100000068000000/), [10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/#/ArcGIS_10_1_Engine/015100000068000000/), [10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/systemrequirements/index.html#/ArcGIS_Engine_10_System_Requirements/015100000068000000/)
- ArcReader [10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/#/ArcReader_10_1/015100000067000000/), [10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/systemrequirements/index.html#/ArcReader_10_System_Requirements/015100000067000000/)

The ArcGIS install packages include installation documentation.

All I know about QGIS system requirements is [this](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2012-September/019244.html).

Comment: thank you very much gary but this is a hardware and software requirements not a direct link to download a copy of ArcGIS

Answer (score 0):

I was found that esri company not offer a free of charge copy of ArcGIS so you must pay to get one copy of it ^_^, and the previous comment of Grey contains software and hardware requirements to install it.
Also i found direct link to download QGIS for redhat OS on ELGIS repository and here is a direct link just visit [***this***](http://elgis.argeo.org/) and you will found all distributions of linux OS